# SQL server - can connect via remote server but not local machine - why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am able to login to a remote server and connect to a database on another server from there. When I do the same thing from my local machine it fails, giving me the error below -

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 64)

Why does this error happen and how do I fix it ? I am trying to connect via management studio.

What I tried so far -

[Error message: (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075784/error-message-provider-shared-memory-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-th)

It does not work for me. As an aside, I already mentioned what I tried in the first 2 lines of my question. But, it went unnoticed. Those two lines suggest that the problem may be in my local system. But, what could the problem be ?

Comment: why vote to close this ?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but it's probably because you've shown no effort to solve this yourself. Did you even Google for a solution? Did you try searching here? Have you researched *anything at all* in an effort to find any information? I don't see anything that would indicate that you have done so. You haven't even indicated *how you're trying to connect* - is it from code, from SQL Server Management Studio, or some other way?

Comment: What's the server name you were trying to use?

Comment: @KenWhite - I edited the question. Is it okay now ?

Comment: @Szymon - a name like GENSERV.dev

Comment: Your first two sentences do not say anything about what you tried to **solve the problem**. They are a vague mention of what the problem is you're trying to solve, which is not the same thing. Trying a single link's solution when a Google search on the simple phrase "sql server error  64" returns many on the first page alone is not a reasonable effort to research or solve the problem, IMO.

Comment: Are you RDPing into the DB server then using SSMS successfully but failing when you try to connect to the same DB from your local machine across the LAN? If so then check the firewall settings and ensure that TCP is enabled on SQL Server. What version of server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are couple things you can to do troubleshoot this:

***Check the server name***: What server name are you using? Are you using the same server name when connecting remotely and locally?

**Check enabled protocols:**  Go to SQL Server configuration manager and check if both TCP/IP and Shared Memory are enabled.

**Check IP address under TCP/IP:** Make sure that the IP address you are using is enabled. This is under Properties for TCP/IP settings

[image]

**Check firewall settings:** It might be possible that server that hosts SQL Server has firewall setup so that it doesn’t accept connections from your local machine but that it does from the other server

Comment: Thanks herb. I just learned that it might be related to security policies. So, probably the SS firewall might be blocking me. Is there any way (like some special cmd command) which will at least tell me the reason why I am not allowed ? Also, ping results in request timed out.