# SQL Server 2008 R2 - User Connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my machine.  When performing any action that requires a connection, I can connect to the server but get an error during login.

## Error Message

> Title: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>   ..............................
>   Failed to connect to server ASUS. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   ..............................
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)
>   For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=233&LinkId=20476

I discovered the reason for this error by following advice found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075784/error-message-provider-shared-memory-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-th/9007978#9007978?newreg=4966c4d3270a4fadb8a8dcc2e090d288). It wasn't the accepted answer, but instead, it was the answer regarding the error log.

## Error Log

> 2015-01-17 13:05:31.06 Logon       Error: 17809, Severity: 20, State: 3.
>   2015-01-17 13:05:31.06 Logon       Could not connect because the maximum number of '2' user connections has already been reached. The system administrator can use sp_configure to increase the maximum value. The connection has been closed. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

It revealed that max user connections is set to 2.  The resolution given is to execute sp_configure to change that value.  Unfortunately for me, it doesn't explain how to accomplish that if you are the admin and only user of the system.

I tried and failed to locate an article that explained this process without the assumption that you had access to the server (dispite the error).  Since none of the connections belonged to the admin/me, I could not perform this action.  I needed to figure out how to release the existing connections.

Comment: Google `DAC` account for sql server and see how you can connect to sql server to manipulate the connection settings.

Comment: That's awesome.  If I had only known, I wouldn't be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing exactly where these connections were being consumed, I decided to try stopping some of the SQL services.  I started by stopping SSRS since I wasn't sure if the others would further impact connection.  This time I was able to connect to the server.  Next, I went to the server properties.  I got the same error again, at this point, but it didn't prevent me from editing the properties.  I set the max concurrent connections to an appropriate value, restarted the service, and went back to work.

## Summary

1. Stop a subset of SQL services
2. Connect to the server in SSMS
3. Update max concurrent connections
4. Restart SQL Server
5. Restart any of the services that were stopped in step 1 if needed.