# The SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service failed to start due to the following error: The pipe has been ended

Tags: sql-server

I am facing one problem related to SQL Server 2005. On our client server SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) service stopped due to any reason. When I am trying to start that SQL service then that time It gives below error:

> The request failed or the service did not responds in a timely
>   fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for
>   details.

When I had checked in to Event Viewer for Error's details then found the error:

> The SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service failed to start due to the
>   following error:  The pipe has been ended.

Can any one please let me know how I can solve the above problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you gone throught services.msc and manually run the SQLEXPRESS service

Comment: @JCBorlagdan, Yes I have checked using services.msc as well its show me below error:  
Windows could not start the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESSS) service on Local Computer.
Error 109: The pipe has been ended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075784/error-message-provider-shared-memory-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-th)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the Error: (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.), when you see that error the service is already running and there is an issue connecting, usually because of a connection limit or the authentication mode is wrong (user tries to use sql login when mixed mode is not enabled.) I am having this same error and trying to figure it out myself