# I can not access my SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXcoe.jpg)

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to DELL\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)
>
> No process is on the other end of the pipe

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075784/error-message-provider-shared-memory-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-th

Comment: Which programming language or tool are you using? Can you share code which causes the isue?

Answer (score 0):

**try this after close sql server :** 
1 - open task manager  .
2 - go to services tab . 
3 - run SQLSERVERAGENT services  . 
4 - run sql server .