# SQL Server 2012, No process is on the other and of the pipe (Microsoft SQL server Error: 233)

Tags: sql-server-2012

Please help, I cannot login to SQL server with error:
 "A Connection was succesfully established with server, but than an error accurred during the login process. (Provider: Shared memory provider, error:0 - No Process is on the other of the pipe (Microsoft SQL server Error: 233).

I've checked the windows Aplication log, there is an information: "Login succeeded for user 'B1admin'. COnnection made using SQL server authentication".
I also checked the authentication mode, it use SQL server and windows Authentication Mode.
I'm using RDP connection.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your Named piped Protocol enabled ?

Comment: Hi Adarsh,
Thanks for your reply,
Yes, named piped protocol is enable.

Comment: in the native client protocols all the below should be enabled 1. Shared memory 2. tcp/ip and Named pipes make sure based on your requirement the order is specified

Comment: And one more thing how are you connecting it are you using management studio ? or are you using  sqlcmd

Comment: Hi Adarh,
I have checked on SQL Server Configuration Manager and I heave already make sure 3 option that you mentioned is enabled.
I have also checked the Service of SQL Server and SQL Server Browser, that Service is running and also restart before.
I'm connecting using Management Studio.

Comment: i link to similar question there are couple things suggested please try them out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075784/error-message-provider-shared-memory-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-th

Comment: Hi Adarsh,
I have tried that link before you tell, but still no luck.