# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process, but the problem is in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I am trying to scaffold a database with Entity framework core and it gives me the following error:

`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)`

After doing some research I allowed Named Pipes in SQL Server Configuration Manager and that fixed the problem on the SQL side, but I still get the same error when I enter the following code in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2019:

`PM>  Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=MediStock_DB;User ID=MyUsername; pwd=MyPassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`

I have also given the user I am trying to log in with all the possible permissions. At this point, I am lost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075784/error-message-provider-shared-memory-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-th/8076038